# Modify a material at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to modify a material's parameter at runtime. The parameter is called "Radio 1" and is defined in a custom shader. I need the change I make to the material to affect all objects that are using it, and that's not working.
How can I do so?

I've tried getting one of the objects that use the material and modify the sharedMaterial, and also tried loading the material and modifying it like this:

```
var mater = Resources.Load("BGRingMat") as Material;
mater.SetFloat("Radio2", bgRingMaterialRadio2);
```

I see no effects at all.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that a typo?  You state above the parameter is called "Radio 1" but you SetFloat on "Radio2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your case. It should be able to work as you desire it to. If you don't get any nullrefs, the only error I can imagine is that "Radio2" is a wrong variable name. If you try to modify a variable using a wrong name, you will not get any errors. In your text you mention the variable as "Radio 1".

Comment: You were right, I had declared the shader's property as "_Radio2 ("Radio 2", Float) = 0.6", I was using "Radio2" instead of "_Radio2"

Answer (score 0):

Globally modify the shader value for all instances of this material:

```
Material mat = Resources.Load("BGRingMat") as Material;
mat.SetFloat( "Radio2", bgRingMaterialRadio2);
```

Or modify for 1 object:

```
renderer.material = Resources.Load("BGRingMat") as Material;
renderer.material.SetFloat( "Radio2", bgRingMaterialRadio2);
```

Note that IF you modify an object's material directly first, and then try to use the shared material, nothing will happen:

```
Material mat = Resources.Load("BGRingMat") as Material;

// Sets Radio2 to bgRingMaterialRadio2
renderer.material.SetFloat( "Radio2", bgRingMaterialRadio2);

// Doesn't do anything to the current object as this object now has its own copy.
mat.SetFloat( "Radio2", 0.0f);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I always set shared material parameters through material directly. And AFAIK the should exist only one instance o a material in order to share it, so I think that renderer.material is just a reference to the previously created shared material.

Comment: @Heisenbug You're correct, bad assumption on my part.  But, renderer.material is not shared.  Renderer.material, as far as I can tell, when first called creates a unique instance of the shader for that object.  Otherwise SetFloat would always modify the shared shader.  You can test this with my last code bit.  I'm assuming internally this just creates another pass with for this shader/mesh combination.